# Save HTML textfield value into a session variable

Tags: html, asp.net

In my ASPX page, I have two HTML textfields:

```
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="9" name="agent1"></div>
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="9" name="agency1"></div>
```

I am trying to save the text field value into a session variable:
Session["Agent"] = agent1.Text;
Session["Agency"] = agency1.Text;

It is giving me an error, I need to use HTML text field not ASP textbox, please advise the way to store the value into a session variable.

Comment: Check the name of your class in code behind vs. the inherits class at the top of your aspx page and make sure they are the same. Then if they are the same, make sure that there is not another page with the same class name in the code behind within the same website project. Also if using webforms, you will need an ID property and runat="server", as already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="9" name="agent1" id="agent1" runat="Server" />
```

that's all you need , set the id , and runat = server

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, unfortunately it did not solve my issue, on my aspx.cs page, I have the error Session["Agent"] = agent1.Text; -error: The name agent1 does not exist in the current context

Comment: try capital s , Runat="Server"  that is exactly how you make it so it is accessable in the code behind, that is exactly the answer you were looking for

Comment: oh-  don't forget to close your input />  and the end , not >

Comment: @ScottSelby: +1. but remember `runat=server` is case-insensitive.

Comment: @naveen - I know html is , but haven't touched web forms in 4 years

Comment: @ScottSelby: I meant to tell you that your answer was correct at the first place. No need for pascal casing :)